Loop problem using For and the conditional if in by JavaScript
I built a function in JavaScript called oddNumbers which I used a for loop and if condition in order to print the odd numbers between 0 to 10. However, the console printed only "Odd: 1".
I have traied to print odd numbers list from 0 to 10 using the following code:
function oddNumbers() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) !== 0)
            return console.log('Odd: ', i);
    }
}

oddNumbers();

But, it only prints "Odd: 1" in the console. Could you please help me with this issue? I haven't found what can be the error or errors yet.

The return statement will exit your function.
change the code to:
function oddNumbers() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) !== 0)
            console.log('Odd: ', i);
    }
}

oddNumbers();

